# Drop down alert always top of screen - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I need an alert system to tell the user if their latest changes have been saved in my web app. My ideal method would be to have a small alert box that drops from the top of the screen (wherever they are on the page) and tells the user of the current status.

How can I do this in the Angular way?

I have some flags that tell me when and what to show in this box, but I have no idea how to get it always fixed to the top of the screen without using jQuery.

Comment: You can fix something to the screen with simple CSS, position:"fixed". Is that the only problem you're having?

Comment: can u make a fiddle or plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in a nutshell the 'AngularJS' way would involve:

- creating a notification service with an interface for publishing and subscribing to events
- creating a directive that subscribes to the notification service and handles rendering the markup for the notifications; and you roll your own using Angular's jqLite or jQuery, or wrap your directive around a jQuery notification plugin, like [Toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html), then place the directive on your layout

I prototyped a working concept of what this would look like [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jDawOzNzyH5mebWcEUxc?p=preview).  Obviously it's primitive.  Besides styling the 'notifications', there's work to handle queuing up notifications, etc.  But I think that shows the basic concept.

Anyway, now you can inject the Notifications service into any components of your application and fire notifications at it.